# The signIn function always returns to "wrong information"

Tags: javascript

```js
var database = [{
    username: '1',
    password: '2',
  },
  {
    username: '3',
    password: '4',
  },
];
var newsfeed = [{
    username: 'Bobby',
    timeline: 'So tired from all that learning!',
  },
  {
    username: 'Sally',
    timeline: 'Javascript is sooooo cool!',
  },
  {
    username: 'Mitch',
    timeline: 'Javascript is preeetyy cool!',
  },
];


var userNamePrompt = prompt('Enter username:');
var passwordPrompt = prompt('Enter password:');
function signIn(username, password) {
  database.forEach(function (username, password) {
      if (username === database.username && password === database.password) {
        console.log(newsfeed);
      }

      console.log('Wrong information');
    }
  );
}
signIn(userNamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

Edited: I suspect that the condition inside the if statement((`username === database.username && password === database.password`) always results in false for some reason.

Comment: Please provide more code showing what `database` is.

Comment: You do not have a reference to database in your function. Do you have it in the global scope?

Comment: It's a simple typo: it should be `forEach`, not `foreach`.

Comment: `forEach()` is an array method, perhaps `database` isn't an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the callback function of forEach returns the instance of the database element. So change it to :

```js
var databases = [{
    username: '1',
    password: '2',
  },
  {
    username: '3',
    password: '4',
  },
];
var newsfeed = [{
    username: 'Bobby',
    timeline: 'So tired from all that learning!',
  },
  {
    username: 'Sally',
    timeline: 'Javascript is sooooo cool!',
  },
  {
    username: 'Mitch',
    timeline: 'Javascript is preeetyy cool!',
  },
];


var userNamePrompt = prompt('Enter username:');
var passwordPrompt = prompt('Enter password:');
function signIn(username, password) {
  databases.forEach(function (database) {
      if (username === database.username && password === database.password) {
        console.log(newsfeed);
      }
      else{console.log('Wrong information');}

      
    }
  );
}
signIn(userNamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

I suggest this one :

```js
var databases = [{
    username: '1',
    password: '2',
  },
  {
    username: '3',
    password: '4',
  },
];
var newsfeed = [{
    username: 'Bobby',
    timeline: 'So tired from all that learning!',
  },
  {
    username: 'Sally',
    timeline: 'Javascript is sooooo cool!',
  },
  {
    username: 'Mitch',
    timeline: 'Javascript is preeetyy cool!',
  },
];


var userNamePrompt = prompt('Enter username:');
var passwordPrompt = prompt('Enter password:');
function signIn(username, password) {
  for(let i = 0; i<databases.length;i++){
  const database = databases[i];
      if (username === database.username && password === database.password) {
        console.log(newsfeed);
        return
      }
      
    }
    console.log('Wrong information');
  
}
signIn(userNamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

Comment: ```
script.js:30 (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
script.js:32 Wrong information
```
This is displayed instead. Is there any way that if console.log(newsfeed); is reached, don't do anything below? I've tried `return` but didn't work.

Comment: Foreach runs for every instance. so, it logs correct for correct ones and wrong for wrong ones

Comment: return of foreach is the return of callback. Not return of parent function

Answer (score 0):

The parameters passed to the forEach callback are not the properties of the objects in the database array, but the object itself.

You would need to access the properties of that object in the function.

```js
database.forEach(function (obj) {
      if (obj.username === database.username && obj.password === database.password) {
        console.log(newsfeed);
      }

      console.log('Wrong information');
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your original code and found some problems.
First of all, forEach does not work as you expect. It sends an element of an array into the callback function on every iteration. Like this:

```
array.forEach( function(elementOfArray) { return ... }
```

In your code every element is an object, so you can check its values with

```
var database = [{
    username: '1',
    password: '2',
  },
  {
    username: '3',
    password: '4',
  },
];

var userNamePrompt = prompt('Enter username:');
var passwordPrompt = prompt('Enter password:');

function signIn(username, password) {
  var userIsFound = false;
  database.forEach(function (user) {
    if (username === user.username && password === user.password) {
      userIsFound = true;
    };
  })
  if (userIsFound) return 'access granted'
  return 'access denied'
}
```